# WhatsApp page not loading in cypress

Tags: cypress, whatsapp

Whatsapp web page and whatsapp websites are not loading when we execute the cypress scipts.

[image]

Comment: How have you troubleshoot this issue? What results did you get? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp probably detects that you are using automated software to do something on their website and blocks it. You shouldn't do that anyhow, don't test third party software, even cypress discourages it. Use [stubs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub).